# Ubuntu 20.04 upgrades - DNS name resolution fails on internal network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, ubuntu-20.04, netplan

My company distributes software to clients on Ubuntu VMs. Recently we've been updating all client VMs from Ubuntu 16/18 to Ubuntu 20.04.

We've been having an issue where DNS name resolution isn't working on the internal network. It's working outside of the network (we're able to ping external websites), but we're not able to connect to machines on the internal network by DNS name - only by IP address. In many cases we were able to resolve internal DNS names on the old VMs (Ubuntu 16/18), but it's not working when we install the new VM using the same network settings.

We usually set the VM up with a static IP. The client's IT gives us their network info and internal dns server(s), and we set up our `00-installer-config.yaml` file accordingly

`/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` example setup:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s10f0:
      addresses: [192.168.10.200/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.10.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.10.1, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, etc.]
  version: 2
```

On the old VMs, often we couldn't ping internal machines by DNS name until we added the local domain name. Eg. `ping fs01` wouldn't work but `ping fs01.clientdomain.local` would work. However, on the Ubuntu VMs this doesn't seem to be helping at all. We always have to revert to the IP address of a file server rather than using the domain name. In most cases this is fine since the IP is static and not subject to change, but this isn't always the case and we'd prefer to be able to connect via DNS name.

Networking and domains really aren't my strong suit. If anyone could make suggestions of things to try or areas to research that would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I tried the suggestion of adding the internal nameserver IP address to the `nslookup` command and took some screenshots. It does look like the VM is able to find the host with `nslookup`, but only when I include the nameserver IP explicitly.

192.168.1.4 is the nameserver and also the host that we're trying to connect to.

**Note:** This was working on the old Ubuntu 18.04 VM, using the same internal nameserver and the FQDN hostname.

*Regular Ping*

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ping <hostname.domain.local>
    ping: <hostname.domain.local>: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

*Simple nslookup*

```
user@ubuntu:~$ nslookup <hostname.domain.local>
    Server:     127.0.0.53
    Address:    127.0.0.53#53

    ** server can't find <hostname.domain.local>: SERVFAIL
```

*nslookup with nameserver IP*

```
user@ubuntu:~$ nslookup <hostname.domain.local> 192.168.1.4 
    Server:     192.168.1.4## Heading ##
    Address:    192.168.1.4#53

    Name:       <hostname.domain.local>
    Address:    192.168.1.85
    Name:       <hostname.domain.local>
    Address:    192.168.1.4
```

In this case, the 192.168.1.4 nameserver was the only nameserver entry in our yaml file. So I don't see how this could be some sort of issue with the order of nameservers in the file.

Also note I tried adding the local domain in the `search:` parameter. I didn't expect this would change the results, but tried it in any case - no change:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s10f0:
      addresses: [192.168.1.21/24]
      gateway4: <gateway>
      nameservers:
        search: [<domain.local>]
        addresses: [192.168.1.4]
  version: 2
```

Comment: so can you ping the internal DNS server? do you get a difference in results when using `nslookup <LAN host FQDN> <ip address of DNS server>` than you do just using `nslokup <LAN host FQDN>` ? one tip, to use hostnames for name resolution instead of FQDNs you want to add a setting called a search domain. in your yml, add a line in the nameservers block like `search:  [yourDomain.Name]` . with that set, the client will try to append the search domain to not-fully-qualified names before sending it to the server, so you don't have to `ping fs1.yourDomain.Name` .

Comment: Thanks for the response - we are able to ping the internal DNS server. Nslookup fails when only specifying the host, but I don't think we've tried specifying the IP of the DNS server in the nslookup command - we will definitely try that next time this happens. I didn't know about the `search:` parameter, that's great to know!

Comment: ok. well be sure to test that it works when you `nslookup <fqdn>`. if that doesn't work, it indicates that your network config is using the wrong DNS server, and you need to reorder or remove entries from the nameservers:addresses setting, or that that server doesn't have an A-record for the host.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'll add an update to my post as soon as we have a chance to try this on a client system

Comment: It looks like the system is ignoring your nameservers specification, and using a local DNS resolver. I'm going to guess that is because you are using the .local TLD, which is commonly associated with zero-conf networking which uses decentralized multi-cast DNS.

Comment: check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040595/dns-at-systemds-127-0-0-53-is-ignoring-some-lookups